# Spring JPA select where element in collection

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have an Entity `Person` and an Entity `Session`. A `Session` has a `@ManyToMany` collection of `Person`s. Now I would like to select all persons who are contained in the `persons` collection of **any** session. What I tried is:

```
    @Query("select p from Person p where p in (select s.persons from Session s)")
    fun findAllInAnySession(): MutableIterable<Person>
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from session session1_ cross join session_persons persons2_, person person3_ whe' at line 1
```

I am using MySQL as database.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems you want to select all the `Person` associated to an `Session`. 
Did you tryed `"Select s.persons From Session s"`

Comment: could you rename your session table to another name, may be it is used by mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use a complex object in an IN clause, even in JPQL. You are trying to assert if a person entity is a member of a collection of persons in your query, which sounds acceptable, but in my opinion JPA provider can not handle such a query. I think the following query can return what you want:

```
select s, p from Sessions s join s.persons p
```